# Change the background color of a specific table view cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am writing code that shows the table of contents of a book.
If I am reading a page included in a particular table of contents, I want to show the color of the table of contents cell in red.

if,

`chaptersList?.chapters[indexPath.row].chapterPage`

is 7, 43, 54, 73

and

`self.bookPage`

is 80....

The code below is `self.bookPage` larger than 7,43,54,73, so all four cells are displayed in red.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChaptersCell") as! ChaptersCell

        cell.chapterPageLbl.text = "\(chaptersList?.chapters[indexPath.row].chapterPage ?? "" )"

        if (self.bookPage ?? 0) > Int(chaptersList?.chapters[indexPath.row].chapterPage ?? "") ?? 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        }

        return cell
    }
```

But the code I want is
`self.bookPage` Table of contents included 80 `chaptersList? .chapters[indexPath.row].chapterPage` 73 I want to display only cells in red....

Comment: Cells are reused. You need an `else` for your `if`.

Comment: Whenever you are writing cell.background color, expected to write else case ..otherwise results will be different.

Comment: cell is reusable you should set default background color programmatically before check your if, or use ternary operator - cell.backgroundColor = (self.bookPage ?? 0) > Int(chaptersList?.chapters[indexPath.row].chapterPage ?? "") ?? 0 ? .red : .white